# Does entropy increase exponentially as the number of observations increase?

Tags: exponentiation, information-theory, entropy

Is there an example that demonstrates that Shannon's information entropy ($H(X)$ formula below) will always increase exponentially as the number of observations in the data increases (preferably using the natural logarithm, $\ln$)? What implications does this have for using it as a measure of uncertainty, and for using estimators of entropy?

Is there a work-around for this, and for which applications would someone want to suppress this behavior?

$$H(X) = -\sum_i p_i\ln(p_i)$$

Comment: I find that your question is not very clear. Which entropy are you talking about ? If you partially observe the state of some variable, then the entropy will decrease on average. Maybe, you are talking about the entropy of a set of n i.i.d variable where entropy will increase linearly (not exponentially) with n. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Shannon's entropy. I've added a formula of it in the question

Comment: The entropy of which variable are you talking about ? Can you explain your problem using dices for instance.

Comment: continuous random variable, more specifically financial returns that are non-i.i.d., so i should actually be putting the differential entropy formula up, but anyway, the data's probabilities would be discretized in order to use a discretized estimator of the entropy currently shown.

Comment: The question is still unclear. The entropy depends on probability, and probability does not depend on "observations".

Comment: Let me put it this way, Does entropy increase exponentially if we admit 1,000 more *probability observations* (i.e. number of probability observations) into a data series?